# Select latest 13 months data

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I would like to select the latest 13 months data from an oracle database.  The DATE is showing as '16/04/2020, 00:00:00'.  I have tried the following however it is ignoring the where statement and returning all data:

```
select *
from DM.DATE COMMON_DATE
where
to_date(COMMON_DATE.DATE,'dd/mm/yyyy') <= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MON'), -1)
```

thanks

Comment: What is the data type of the column?

Comment: The data_type says its DATE and data length 7 even though I see it as '16/04/2020, 00:00:00'.  Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Your date datatype looks like a string, because of the comma.  I suggest that you put your efforts into fixing the data!  Dates should be stored using `date`, `timestamp` or related types.

In your case, though, you can parse out the date.  I assume that you want:

```
where to_date(substr(common_date.date, 1, 10), 'DD/MM/YYYY') >= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MON'), -13)
```

EDIT:

If the column is already a `date`, then you don't need to convert it:

```
where common_date.date >= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MON'), -13)
```

Comment: Thanks for this,  I tried it but get this error message 'ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Comment: @Sa . . . As I say, don't store dates as strings!  You would need to fix the data.  Or explain what to do if the date is not recognized.

Comment: The data_type says its DATE and data length 7 even though I see it as '16/04/2020, 00:00:00'.